# java custom colorChooserPanel

Tags: java, jcolorchooser

i want to create a custom `ColorChooserPanel` for `JcolorChooser` in java swing.

```
public class ColorPanel  extends AbstractColorChooserPanel {

    public void buildChooser() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        makeAddButton("Red", Color.red);
        makeAddButton("Green", Color.green);
        makeAddButton("Blue", Color.blue);  }

        public void updateChooser() {
        }
        public String getDisplayName() {
            return "MyChooserPanel";  }

        public Icon getSmallDisplayIcon() {
            return null;  }

        public Icon getLargeDisplayIcon() {
            return null;  }

        private void makeAddButton(String name, Color color) {
            JButton button = new JButton(name);
            button.setBackground(color);
            button.setAction(new AbstractAction() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    JButton button = (JButton) arg0.getSource();
                    getColorSelectionModel().setSelectedColor(button.getBackground());

            }});
            add(button);  }
}
```

It should show 3 color button but instead it shows 6 button. May anyone show me where did I get something wrong? And how can I remove the panel below.

```
ColorPanel colorPanel  = new ColorPanel();
colorPanel.buildChooser();
colorChooser =  new JColorChooser();
colorChooser.addChooserPanel(colorPanel);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1fag.png

another question : can i remove the recent pane by swatches color panel . I just want to show only the color pallete . I mean the "recent" part in the picture below .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfdDJ.png

Comment: Can you  show us where `buildChooser()` is called?  This may be relevant to a helpful answer.

Comment: i do it like that ( see my last edited question )

Comment: I quite don't understand your second question, try to ask one problem per question

Answer (score 0):

```
ColorPanel colorPanel  = new ColorPanel();
// colorPanel.buildChooser(); <-- remove this line
```

When you add `colorPanel` to a `JChooserPanel`, this method get called:

```
public void installChooserPanel(JColorChooser enclosingChooser) {
    if (chooser != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException ("This chooser panel is already installed");
    }
    chooser = enclosingChooser;
    chooser.addPropertyChangeListener("enabled", enabledListener);
    setEnabled(chooser.isEnabled());
    buildChooser();
    updateChooser();
}
```

So you don't need to "build" your panel again since it's already built when you added it to the `colorChooser`.

Comment: i've tried this but it doesn't solve the problem . And for the  second question i've addes another picture . Thank you.